# WSO2 ESB cache mediator timeout

Tags: caching, configuration, timeout, wso2-esb

We are using cache mediator and want to make the timeout property of the cache mediator configurable (reading value from registry or some local property)

We tried few options but looks like it takes constant value integer value only .

Any inputs on the same

Comment: I also needed this requirement like following code. <cache collector="false" maxMessageSize="6291456" timeout='{get-property("TIME_OUT_PROP")}'></cach>

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK You can not change this value dynamically. It is always going to take the value you give when creating the cache mediator nevertheless this value can not be change dynamically.